# Convert int to value when changing datatype in column

Tags: liquibase

Is it possible with liquibase to do some kind of mapping when doing a `modifyDataType`?

Considering the following example:

```xml
<changeSet id="1" author="me">
    <createTable tableName="person">
        <column name="id" type="int">
            <constraints primaryKey="true" nullable="false" />
        </column>
        <column name="firstName" type="varchar(100)"></column>
        <column name="lastName" type="varchar(100)"></column>
        <column name="marital_status" type="int">
            <constraints nullable="false" />
        </column>
    </createTable>
</changeSet>
<changeSet id="2" author="me">
    <modifyDataType tableName="person" columnName="type"
        newDataType="varchar(36)" />
</changeSet>
```

I would like in my column 'type' that the following mapping occurs:

```
0->single
1->married
etc..
```

Is this possible with liquibase? I'm using it via the command line.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is not possible directly via some kind of mapping or refactoring.

One way to do this is using `sql` and put this into another changeset which is run right after the one that changes the data type:

```xml
<changeSet id="3" author="me">
    <sql>
        update person set martial_status = 'single' where martial_status = 0;
        update person set martial_status = 'married' where martial_status = 1;
    </sql>
</changeSet>
```

I just wrote this down as an idea. It is untested.

You could add a [precondition](http://www.liquibase.org/documentation/preconditions.html) to execute this changeset only if changeset with id 2 ran successful.

Comment: I used the <update> command instead of the <sql> to stay DB agnostic but for the rest it worked well. thanks